# To get safe area or the height of the home indicator, is it safe to use UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.safeAreaInsets?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

Normally, to get safe are, UIViewController.view.safeAreaInsets in layoutSubviews() should be used.
UIViewController.view.safeAreaInsets is zero in viewDidLoad().
But you can get safe area in viewDidLoad() by using UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.safeAreaInsets.

I think using UIViewController.view.safeAreaInsets in layoutSubviews() is the proper way to get safe area.
So, I think UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.safeAreaInsets in viewDidLoad() might behave unexpectedly in the future iOS update or some existing devices.

Is it safe to use UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.safeAreaInsets in viewDidLoad()?
If it is safe or not safe, I would like to know the reason.
My app layouts views in viewDidLoad().
So, I want to get safe area in viewDidLoad() by using UIApplication.shared.keyWindow, if it is safe.

Answer (score 0):

in iOS 11.0.1 iPhone6 use keywindow. safeAreaInsets is zero.So I think is not safe enough